# Android: Precise timing to play audio

Tags: android, audio, timer

I'm writing an android App that plays music using recorded samples (using SoundPool). I have a Player that checks which samples I have to play depending on the current time (realTimeElapsed). The Player gets updated with a Timer that I set to 1 ms. Most of the time this works fine, but sometimes I have some delays of about 100ms.

I could not find a way to increase the priority of the timer, is there another way to get of these delays?

I'm rendering a scene using openGL at the same time, but I get the same delays if I disable all drawings.

Thanks

Edit:

I analyzed it with TraceView: The audio thread (Thread-16) gets executed every ms. But at t=2580 there is break of about 200ms. The thread is not in sleep during this period but in the method SoundPool.play and gets interrupted. Every time I have such a delay, the audio thread gets interrupted. Isn't there a way to prevent these interruptions?

I've set the priority of the GL Thread (that interrupts the audio thread) to THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST.
[image: TraceView]

right click the image and select "show image" or somethng near that to see the image in full resolution.

Comment: 200ms sounds suspiciously large. Is it possible that it is due to garbage collection? There is a message that gets printed to logcat when a garbage collection occurs. Just make sure that it is a message from your process, not some other random process.

Comment: There is no GC running at this time, you would see the GC in the TraceView. During this 200ms, the OpenGL thread is running all the time (please right click the image and select "show image" or somethng near that to see the image in full resolution)

Comment: It has to be a problem of the Soundpool, if I don't call the play method of the SoundPool, I have no delays at all. I'll have to open a new thread for this problem

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying [Handler.postDelayed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) instead of Timer, and see if you get better results.

If not, maybe just a thread with a short [Thread.Sleep()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long,%20int%29), and a check on [System.nanoTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried both but with no real success: using Handler.postDelayed is about the same as the Timer; I'm currently using an own Thread with high priority and sleep for one ms, but I still get delays of about 100ms...